# My Direct3D scene update is not working. What am I missing out?

Tags: c#, winforms, directx

I have a winform and have setup direct3d on it to show a blue screen.
`Render` is is running every frame.
The following (and some vertex declarations above) output a triangle to the screen.. all cool so far.

```
    public void UpdateScene()
    {
        Vector3 translation = new Vector3 { X = whatever.X, Y = whatever.Y, Z = whatever.Z };
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.Translate(translation);
        device.Transform.World = matrix;
    }


    public void Render()
    {
        if (device == null)
            return;

        //Clear the backbuffer to a blue color 
        device.Clear(ClearFlags.Target, System.Drawing.Color.Blue, 1.0f, 0);
        //Begin the scene
        UpdateScene();
        device.BeginScene();

        // Rendering of scene objects can happen here
        device.SetStreamSource(0, vertexBuffer, 0);
        device.VertexFormat = CustomVertex.TransformedColored.Format;
        device.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 1);


        //End the scene
        device.EndScene();
        device.Present();
    }
```

The cameraPosition.X Y and Z are updating correctly on each pass... Any ideas why my object does not appear to move backwards and forwards (or moreso the camera move around it)?

Also tried this:

```
Vector3 translation = new Vector3 { X = whatever.X, Y = whatever.Y, Z = whatever.Z };
device.Transform.World.Translate(translation);
```

and this:

```
Vector3 translation = new Vector3 { X = whatever.X, Y = whatever.Y, Z = whatever.Z };
device.Transform.World = Matrix.Translation(translation);
```

**Code I think is relevant:** http://pastebin.com/rgfJGxk0

Comment: Your second two code snippets have the camera position components put into a new Vector3, but your first code snippet has X = cameraPosition.Z, Y = cameraPosition.Y, Z = cameraPosition.Z -- is this intentional?

Comment: thanks, and no it wasn't hehe

Comment: can you show use the code how you update the camera?

Answer (score -1):

You'd better not transform the triangle to the same location with your camera. the Direct3D transform and projection algorithm was based on the real world example, just like you capture an image with your camera. so just imagine, if you put something at the same position of your camera, can you capture it? you need some distance between them.

Comment: Ignore the variable names, I have one model that is called camera position at the moment, this will all be changed. the problem is that I can't get the triangle to move into and out of Z because the translation seems to not be doing anything.

Comment: really bad variable names.